# Can the Lorentz Force and Magnetic Moment be related?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

I have learned that the Lorentz Force, $\vec F = q \vec E + q \vec  v \times \vec B$, describes the electric and magnetic forces on a charge, such as a proton or an electron. I understand that, in this context, the magnetic force can be explained as an electric force caused by length contractions and differences in reference frames. I have also learned about magnetic moment, which relates the magnetic field an object is in to the torque and magnetic force it experiences. However, I am having a bit of trouble unifying these concepts. I am thinking that it has something to do with the intrinsic magnetic moment of the electron, and that the magnetic force on the electron, described by $q \vec v \times \vec B$, relates to the intrinsic magnetic moment somehow. I was thinking that since the magnetic moment of a magnet is related to the magnetic moments of the constituent atoms, then magnetic moment is simply a way of describing the sum of magnetic force on charges on a macroscopic scale. Is my thinking correct, or do these ideas relate in some other way? Or do these phenomena simply not relate, and they are both called magnetism because they both experience a force in a magnetic field?

Thank you

Comment: If is possible to derive the magnetic moment torque formula $\vec{\tau} = \vec{\mu} \times \vec{B}$ and force formula $\vec{F} = \vec{\nabla} ( \vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{B})$ from the Lorentz force law. To do this, you can consider a very tiny square loop of current in an external magnetic field. Doing Taylor expansions to write the torque and force on each of the four components of wires, and remembering to use $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}$, will get you the desired result. It's somewhat tedious but a good exercise to see how they can be derived from the Lorentz force law.

Comment: Akash, the existence of the intrinsic magnetic moment of the electron is overshadowed by the thinking of the electron as a charge. May you want to read https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/192708